# Query when parameter is none django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to make a query, something like

```
Model.objects.filter(x=x).filter(y=y).filter(z=z)
```

... but there are some cases when for example y is None. This literally searches the database for null values in the y column -- is there a nifty way to essentially disregard that query parameter if it is none, i.e. return the queryset

```
Model.objects.filter(x=x).filter(z=z)?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not know, if I get your question, but

```
Model.objects.filter(x=x, y__isnull = False, z=z)
```

gives you the queryset, where the `y`column is non-null (`IS NOT NULL`).

[Here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) the relevant documentation.

EDIT: Check if y is None and build your queryset dynamically:

```
if y is None:
    qs = Model.objects.filter(x=x).filter(z=z)
elif z is None:
    qs = Model.objects.filter(x=x).filter(y=y)
...
```

If there are too many arguments to deal with, you could use something like this; assuming that `x`, `y`, `z` are stored in a dictionary `your values`:

```
your_values = { 'x' : 'x value', 'y' : 'y value', 'z' : 'value'}
arguments = {}
for k, v in your_values.items():
    if v:
        arguments[k] = v

Model.objects.filter(**arguments)
```

Comment: Edited my question a tad but no, that's not my question. If I POST x and z, but not y, then I want to be able to find all elements that contain x and z regardless of if they contain y. As it stands, it assumes y is None, and pulls out all elements with x, z, and y=None.

Comment: Now I have understand what you want to achieve. Please see my answer.

Comment: That leaves me with 8 possible combinations to check for... :(

Comment: I have edited my post, to reflect your comment. It should work for you now :-)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this could work:

```
models = Model.objects.all()

variables = {'x':'x','y':'y','z':'z'}

for key, value in variables.items():
    if key=='x' and value:
        models = models.filter(x=value)
    if key=='y' and value:
        models = models.filter(y=value)
    if key=='z' and value:
        models = models.filter(z=value)
```

Because [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), this doesn't involve any database activity.

Comment: Doesn't this mean I just loaded all 10 billion objects (pardon the exaggeration) into memory though?

Comment: No, because QuerySets are lazy (see the link posted in my answer.) Basically `models = Model.objects.all()` loads nothing into memory, and neither do any of the filters, until you actually evaluate the QuerySet. From the docs: `You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won't actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.`

Comment: After reading that link (lazy querysets) I think the answer is no. I responded to myself a moment too late. Cool, thanks.

Comment: oneliner: Model.objects.filter(**dict([(k, v) for k, v in variables.iteritems() if v]))

Answer (score 4):

A better approach on the otherwise very readable @rolling-stone answer:

```
models = Model.objects.all()

variables = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}

for key, value in variables.items():
    if value is not None:
        models = models.filter(**{key: value})
```

Anyway, depending on the specific filter, you'll need to apply filters together in the same .filter() call, so the "blind" way only works in the simple cases. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships for more information on those cases.

Comment: Indeed, this is nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model manager and then assign it to your model so that you can use this manager to any  model. This solution is more pythonic.

```
class GridManager(models.Manager):

    def applyFilters(self, *args, **kwargs):
         new_kwargs = {}
         for eachKey in kwargs:
             val = kwargs[eachKey]
             if val != '' and val != None:
                 new_kwargs[eachKey] = val
         if new_kwargs:
             return super(GridManager, self).get_query_set().filter(*args, **new_kwargs)
         else:
             return super(GridManager, self).get_query_set()
```

Assign this manager to your model:

```
class some_model(models.Model):
     your fields.....
     ......
     objects = models.Manager()
     grid_manager = GridManager()
```

And in your view you can use the above manager as:

```
objects = some_model.grid_manager.applyFilters(x=value, y = value, z = None)
```

Now you don't have to worry about the none values. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty interesting, I'll have to try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
filters = {'x':'abc', 'y':None, 'z':2}
# here we filter out the None values of the dict 
filters = dict(filter(lambda (k, v): v is not None, filters.items()))

# We use the dict to create the query
qs = Model.objects.filter(**filters)
```