# How to set default value in Django while filtering objects from models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create one function where I am expecting user to enter some details and on the basis of that I need to filter out those data and return it.

For example if in my model name Profile I have:

Name. age, gender then I am trying to do:

`Profile.objects.filter(name=name, age=age, gender=gender)`

name, age and gender are values which will be provided by user. Now if user types name = 'Shashank' and leaves age and gender blank then I need to query it like:

`Profile.objects.filter(name='Shashank')`

While ignoring all those blank values. So I am not sure how to achieve such kind of behaviour. What type of inital value I can set so that it doesn't effect the search result.

`Profile.objects.filter(name='Shashank', age=<VALUE>, gender=<VALUE>)`

Where `<VALUE>` can be ignored by filter function.

NOTE: I don't want to write all the possible combination of filter statement because it will be not convenient.

I tried using `None`, `False` but it was giving wrong result

Answer (score 7):

You can make a manager method for this.

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def myfilter(self, **filters):
        filters = {k:v for k,v in filters.items() if v is not None}
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(**filters)
```

Be sure to set the manager in the model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    objects = ProfileManager()
    # the rest of the model
```

Then you can pass `name` `age` and `gender` (or any other column) to `objects.myfilter` and it will ignore any value of `None`.

```
# assume the following values are retrieved
# name = 'Shashank'
# age = None
# gender = None

qs = Profile.objects.myfilter(name=name, age=age, gender=gender)
```

The qs here should be the same as `objects.filter(name=name)`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, it really helped me a lot and yes it is working as expected. Just for information, it is also possible to do it with django-filter app right ? Because that was my last resort but now it is fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has this exact functionality out of the box, but looking at the docs, it appears it supports [filter customization](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method), so it looks like you *could* use that feature to apply the same solution as above in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution but I've done this way : you chain the filter while checking if the value is not None.

```
qs = Profile.objects.all()
if name:
    qs = qs.filter(name=name)
if age:
    qs = qs.filter(age=age)
if gender:
    qs = qs.filter(gender=gender)
```

Or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006919/8439435) can help you.

Comment: What if there are millions of profile data and I get all the objects and then start filtering it. Will it be fine using this method ? It was really a nice hack to this solution.

Comment: @ShashankSharma Yes you're right, if you have a lot of attribute to filter, this solution is not viable. However, since [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), you can filter a few attributes without bad database performances.