# Filter using Q in Django , when multiple inputs can be null

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-q

I have a model product_details, with the following fields brand_name,model_name, bodystyle, transmission, and min_price, max_price

Example of budget values in the dropdown is

```
1 - 5
5 - 10
10 - 15
```

I have 5 select dropdown fields on the basis of which I want to filter my results.

I am using the method below to filter based on first three fields

```
def select(request):
    q1 = request.GET.get('brand')
    q2 = request.GET.get('model')
    q3 = request.GET.get('bodyStyle')
    #q4 = request.GET.get('budget')


    cars = product_details.objects.filter(Q(bodystyle__icontains=q3)|Q(brand_name__icontains=q1)|Q(model_name__icontains=q2))


    #cars = product_details.objects.filter(bodystyle=q3)
    return render(request, 'search/search_results.html', {'cars': cars})
```

I have two questions

1: How do I filter if only 1 or 2 values are selected from dropdowns. What should be my if condition?
2. How do I filter on the basis of range for budget fields? Since the budget needs to be compared with min_price and max_price.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Model Definition:

```
class product_details(models.Model):

    product_id=models.ForeignKey(products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_id=models.ForeignKey(product_models, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant_id=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)

    brand_name=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    model_name=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    variant_descr=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    transmission=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bodystyle=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


    min_price=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_price=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006862/query-when-parameter-is-none-django

Comment: Thank you, it helps my question 1. Could you please guide me to Question 2?

Comment: If you provide model ill help you

Answer (score 0):

Please respect python CamelCase naming convention:

```py
class ProductDetails(models.Model):
# ...
```

For question 2:

```py
selected_min_price= 50
selected_max_price=200
ProductDetails.objects.filter(additional_filters=...).filter(min_price__gt=selected_min_price, max_price__lt=selected_max_price)
```

See [Object.filter(property__lt=...)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#lt)

Answer (score 0):

`ProductDetails.objects.filter(max_price__lte=200, min_price__gte=100)` <---- this should give you between ranges of 100 & 200

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your queryset multiple times to apply multiple conditions based on the selected filters, eg:

```py
cars = product_details.objects.all()

if q1:
    cars = cars.filter(brand_name__icontains=q1)

if q2:
    cars = cars.filter(model_name__icontains=q2)

if q3:
    cars = cars.filter(bodystyle__icontains=q3)
```

For the budget you can use the same technique, if the budget is selected, first split the two values of the range (min, max), then filter your queryset again:

```py
if q4:
    budget_min, budget_max = q4.split(' - ')
    cars = cars.filter(
        min_price__gte=int(budget_min),
        max_price__lte=int(budget_max),
    )
```